# Silverlight - Opera 10 - JavaScript invoke

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0, opera, invoke

I have problems with invoking javaScript code on page with Opera 10 browser.

JavaScript code on page:

```
function CallMe(){
   alert("It works!");
}
```

And I am invoking this code with:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("CallMe");
```

In all browsers except Opera this works great. In Opera I get error: "failed to invoke: CallMe"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Opera is not one of the supported browsers. See System Requirements tab on the [Silverlight Install page](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx)

Comment: But Silverlight works in Opera and simple JS too. What is the problem then?

Comment: @Gapipro:  Despite the fact that Opera is an unsupported browser for hosting the silverlight plugin it still generally works ok.  However as you have discovered there are somethings that don't work.  All you can really do is vote up this feature suggestion: http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/323983-opera-browser-support

Answer (score 0):

Opera's support for the plugin API (NPAPI) has had some issues that apparently made it different enough from other NPAPI-browsers to break some Silverlight functionality.

This should work in an upcoming Opera version (perhaps even in the next major release). Meanwhile, sorry to have caused you problems :-/